# Auto Increment continuing from last id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on a personal project and i would like to be able to delete SQL and not have autoincrement still go from the last id it was

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: Use `truncate table`.  This will reset the auto increment id as well as removing the contents of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably worth an answer.

```
delete from t
```

and

```
truncate table t
```

are very similar in that they both remove all rows from the the table `t`.  However, `truncate table` has certain other features, such as:

- No logging, so it is faster.
- Resetting the auto-increment value.
- No invocation of triggers.

So, use it to empty your tables and remove all the rows.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) discusses this.

Comment: didnt need to use delete from t but truncate table t worked thanks